# Spark Intersect with WrappedArray

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I performs the following operations like:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import spark.implicits._

val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SameInterest").getOrCreate()

val d1 = spark.read.json ("/path/data1").select("Name","Interest").createOrReplaceTempView("d1_sql")
val d2 = spark.read.json ("/path/data2").select("Name","Interest").createOrReplaceTempView("d2_sql")

val sql_script = "SELECT d1_sql.Name as Name , d1_sql.Interest as Interest1 , d2_sql.Interest as Interest2 FROM d1_sql, d2_sql WHERE d1_sql.Name = d2_sql.Name"

val dosql = spark.sql(sql_script)

val sameIP_UU = dosql.rdd.filter(X => Array(X(1)).intersect(Array(X(2))).length>0)
```

I want to do `intersect` with column `Interest` of d1 and d2, but I can't get the right answer.

The data and schema is :

```
{"name":"John","Interest1":{"bag_0":[{"Interest":"110"},{"Interest":"220"},{"Interest":"333"}]},"Interest2":{"bag_0":[{"Interest":"111"},{"Interest":"222"},{"Interest":"333"}]}}
{"name":"Allen","Interest1":{"bag_0":[{"Interest":"111"},{"Interest":"222"},{"Interest":"333"}]},"Interest2":{"bag_0":[{"Interest":"111"},{"Interest":"222"},{"Interest":"333"}]}}
```

printSchema():

```
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
  |-- Interest1: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |-- bag_0: array (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
  |    |    |    |-- Interest: string (nullable = true)
  |-- Interest2: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |-- bag_0: array (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
  |    |    |    |-- Interest: string (nullable = true)
```

I think the the answer must be 2, but i always get the answer 1.

And I found the data structure have a WrappedArray:
    [WrappedArray([110], [220], [333])]

That may be the reason that I got the wrong answer, but I have no idea how to get the value from WrappedArray and  use `intersect`

**EDIT:**

```
dosql.take(1)
res47: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([John,[WrappedArray([110], [220], [333])],[WrappedArray([110], [220], [333])]])
```

Comment: your code fails immediately on `select("Name","Interest")`, because there's no `Interest` column - should this be `Interest1`? `Interest2`? And is the sample data `/path/data1` or `/path/data2`? Or both?

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't clearly explain my original data structure. data1 and data2 have the same column with name and interest, so i will correctly select value by select("Name","Interest")

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

dosql.rdd.filter {
  row => 
  row.getSeq[Row]("Interest1").intersect(row.getSeq[Row]("Interest1")).size > 0
}
```

Comment: I tried it and still got `error: type mismatch; found   :Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] required: Boolean`